# Loop through a list of keywords from a column in csv file that starts with elements in that list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems that I wasn't able to get my heads right on this. I have a list of keywords to loop through csv file. All these keywords are located in the second column.

```
keywords_list = ['account number','venmo cashout','quickpay']
```

These keywords are just the beginning of each transaction from bank statements and I need to catch every transaction starts with these keywords. Here is the code I tried so far:

```
input_file = '/Users/.../input_file.csv'
output_file = '/Users/.../output_file.csv'
final_output_list = []
with open(input_file,'r') as raw_data_opener:
    key_words_search = csv.reader(raw_data_opener, delimiter=',')
    for j, col in enumerate(key_words_search):
        for i in range(len(keywords_list[i]):
            if col[1].str.startswith(keywords_list[i]): <----something wrong here
                final_output_list.append(col)
with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
     writer=csv.writer(outfile)
     for row in final_output_list:
         writer.writerow(row)
print('Finished...')
```

The issue is there are no line items written in the output file. My guess is there is something wrong in the codes above. Please point me into the right direction and any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
No values are written in output file from vs code console. Also, vs code returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

**EDIT:**
Input_file layout:

```
Col0    Col1                         Col2
Date    Description                  Amount
01/02   Venmo Cashout PPD ID:...     xxxx
```

Desired output: for every line item that start with keywords list

```
Date    Description      Amount
01/02   Venmo Cashout..  xxx
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Also include your debugging attempts.  "guess ... something is wrong" is not proper diagnosis.  If nothing else, insert a couple of useful `print` statements to check the values you're testing.

Comment: @Prune apologies. no issues returned from vs code console and the output file has no line items written in it.

Comment: @Prune Please add an example of the content of `input_file` and an example of the desired output.

Comment: "If nothing else, insert a couple of useful `print` statements to check the values you're testing." Did you try that?

Comment: @Joey edited in OP

Comment: @usr2564301 yes. it returns an empty list.

Comment: The code works by removing `.str` from OP... thanks everyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing `.str` will solve the problem...

```
if col[1].startswith(key_words_list[i]):
```

It will return the line items that start with elements in keywords list